# How can we select tableList row bydefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi i am very new for ios and in my app i have created 
one UItablaList ok fine

here by default my tableList row one textcolor 
i have assigned like "RED"

and when i click on another rows that first row color must be "WHITE" and selected row color must be "RED" and if i click dy default selected first row then that color must be "RED please help me some one ,How can we implement logic for this

### my code:-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    MyCellTableViewCell *cell = (MyCellTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    UILabel *lineLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 55, RightMenuTbl.frame.size.width, 1)];
    lineLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lineLbl];

    //remove background for table:-

   if (indexPath.row == 0) {
      lineLbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
 }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
```

Comment: Best practice for doing this is if you have only one label then you can use  "detailTextLabel" or textLabel property on UITableViewCell. like this.

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"abc";
    cell.textLabel.text =       @"abc";
you can set its color in didSelectRowAtIndexPath as 

cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

you can reset its value in deselectRowAtIndexPath

cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take int as selectedRow in .h file and in didselectrow

```
selectedRow = indexPath.row;
[yourtableview reloadData];
```

and in cellforrow

```
if (selectedRow== indexPath.row) {
    lineLbl.textColor = set color you want for selected
}else
    lineLbl.textColor = set color you want for not
```

selected

Comment: but by default first row color must be red when we run the app

Comment: ok set selectedRow = 0 in viewwill appear or in code where you first time load table

Comment: Hey @AbhiRam what is the status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103179/discussion-between-abhiram-and-vijay-palwe).

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
        -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {

            NSIndexPath * cellIndexPath = indexPath;

            SubCategoryCell * cell = (SubCategoryCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];


             cell.nameLbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];


        }

    (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SubCategoryCell * cell = (SubCategoryCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
cell.nameLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }
```

Comment: what is this is it answer ti my ques?

Comment: yes this will change the text color of selected index label

Comment: my question is not that please see once again

Comment: You want that whatever row you select that row text color changes right

Comment: by default i have already assigned tableList first row text color is "RED" if i select another rows then first row(i mean this is allredy default selected row) color must be "WHITE" and if i select first row(i mean this is allredy default selected row) that color must be like "RED"

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SubCategoryCell * cell = (SubCategoryCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.nameLbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   SubCategoryCell * cell = (SubCategoryCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.nameLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```